# Error: Unresolved compilation problem: RetailItem cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I am only getting one error and cannot seem to fix this error, this is the error
You are buying: Jeans
We have 12 pair In stock.
The price of the jeans are: $59.95
How much are you buying?: 3

******  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        RetailItem cannot be resolved to a variable

```
public class CashRegisterapp 
{
    private final double TAX_RATE = 0.06;
    private double retail;
    private int quantity;
    private RetailItem item;


    public CashRegisterapp(RetailItem item, int q) 
    {
        RetailItem = item;
        quantity = q;

    }
    public double getSubtotal()
    {
        return retail * getSubtotal();
    }
    public double getTax()
    {
        return getSubtotal() * TAX_RATE;
    }
    public double getTotal()
    {
        return getSubtotal() + getTax();
    }
}
```

******Test code below******

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HW5
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int unitsOnHand = 12;
        final double price = 59.95;
        String description = "Jeans";
        int quantity;

        RetailItem item = new RetailItem(description,unitsOnHand,price);
        System.out.print("You are buying: "+ description+ "\nWe have "+ unitsOnHand+ " pair In stock.\nThe price of the jeans are: $"+ price+ "\n");

        System.out.print("How much are you buying?: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        quantity = keyboard.nextInt();


        CashRegisterapp reg = new CashRegisterapp(item, quantity);
        System.out.printf("The subtotal is: $%,.2f\n", reg.getSubtotal());
        System.out.printf("The sale tax is: $%,.2f\n", reg.getTax());
        System.out.printf("The total is: $%,.2f\n", reg.getTotal());
    }
}
```

Comment: To resolve this issue you need to create a object class for "RetailItem", since you have inject data in this class constructor at HW5.java line no 21 (RetailItem item = new RetailItem(description,unitsOnHand,price);). So, you need to create class with 3 variables. But I could not understand why you return "retail * getSubtotal()" inside of getSubtotal() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accidentially wrote `RetailItem` instead of `this.item` in the first line of the constructor of `CashRegisterapp`. Most editors should highlight such problems while you type.

```
public CashRegisterapp(RetailItem item, int q) 
{
    this.item = item;
    this.quantity = q;
}
```

Also, there are other problems with this code:

- your `getSubtotal()` recursively calls itself, this will result in stack overflow
- you don't initialize `retail`

Comment: I will try to make that change, and I am using Visual code Studio the only error it was showing was error variable. I dont know why it didnt flag it. Thank you im new to java

Comment: In VS Code, there is probably some plugin for this, but I have not used it for Java yet.